# Session Expires in Frames

Tags: javascript, session-variables, session-cookies, frames, frameset

I am developing a web application and my requirement is as specified below.

1. I need to display four websites in a single browser window...(which i implemented using frameset)
2. I need to refresh the whole page (which certainly will refresh frames inside ) after 1 minute to update the frames content....(which i implemented using the java script)...

however in one of the frames i need to login to the 3rd party website. i am able to login and able to view the content after the login...however when the page refresh happens after 1 minute the page will be redirected back to the login page again and i have to login after each page refresh...

I googled this and found that it might be due to frames which does not set the cookies.for this i have implemented P3P policy also but the problem persists...

please provide the solution if anybody knows about this...

The javascript I used to refresh a page is

```
function timeRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
        window.setTimeout("location.reload(true);", timeoutPeriod);

    }
    window.onload = timeRefresh(60*1000);
```

Comment: If you disable the refresh and just navigate the 3rd party site does it timeout then? I wonder if the refresh is the issue rather than P3P and cookies?

Comment: Hi..i can navigate within 3rd party web site ....and it is not an issue with page refresh...regarding p3p issue you were quoting i have added p3p policy in Application_BeginRequest() methos in global.asax file.So is it the problem with p3p policy still ? I am using google chrome browser and i can see that web site is able to set the cookies

Comment: If the cookies for the 3rd party site are set then your P3P looks fine. If you can navigate fine for over a minute without losing session then the problem must be the timeRefresh?

Comment: Thank you for your reply..i think i have found where exactly the problem is.The url for that particular frame that i was passing was pointing to login page for each page refresh.thats the reason the page is redirected to login page after each refresh.

Comment: Is it possible to replace the url dynamically using java script or something.What i mean is...assume that i have a login form in www.example.com..and the url of the page after login be www.example.com/user1 .Now,i want to use www.example.com before login and once the user log in then can i replace the url to www.example.com/user1 in "src" property of frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the cookies for the 3rd party site are set then your P3P looks fine and you can navigate fine for over a minute without losing session then the problem must be something with the timeRefresh()

As you can't get a customized URL of the 3rd party site in order to issue a specific reload and assuming that you have no control over the third party site, I suggest you do something different. Set up some JavaScript to load an image from the site (the logo or something else that won't change, or alternatively a script or page) every minute from a frame that you have control over. Because the browser is the same, any existing cookies from a login will be referenced and it will extend the login.